# Can compound index support the matches on the prefixes of the index fields?

Tags: java, mongodb

Consider I have below collection structure

```
"mycoll":{
    "a":"",
    "b":"",
    "c":"",
    "d":"",
    "e":""
}
```

and I have index like

```
{
    "a":1,
    "b":1,
    "c":1,
    "e":1
}
```

My query is like(it has field "d" in the query which is not in index)

```
db.mycoll.find({"a":"?","b":"?","c":"?","d":"?"});
```

Please let me know if my index support the above query?

Comment: It does, but it was quicker for you to use `explain()` than posting the question.

Comment: Thanks, i ll use explain() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, compound index support queries that match on the prefix of the
index fields.

> In addition to supporting queries that match on all the index fields,
>   compound indexes can support queries that match on the prefix of the
>   index fields.

[Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

I have checked with explain() for your query, the winning plan does use index scan.

```
db.mycoll.find({"a":"?","b":"?","c":"?","d":"?"});
```

> "stage" : "IXSCAN"